# Var Dump HTTP POST into fwrite file

Tags: php, arrays

I trying to dump all that was HTTP POST in json to a text file call logs.txt, the file can be written and

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("/var/www/html2/inc/logs/logs.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data = json_decode($_POST, true);

fwrite($myfile, "\n".$data);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

The result was actually empty.. nothing was written. I did try if the file is writeable and yes it created the file, no folder permission issue, I think of using serialize but its not working.

Comment: `$_POST` is an array, trying to use `json_decode` on that makes no sense to begin with. If your PHP script was actually send data _as_ JSON, then you won’t find this in $_POST to begin with. How to handle that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` might be the error.

To convert an array to a JSON you need to use:

```
$json = json_encode($_POST);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The json_decode() function returns an array, not an object, when the flag for associative array is set to true.

Comment: Yeah I missed this. Just saw it.